# How Does this Kernel Call know to grab from the Counter Register

Tags: assembly, x86, system-calls, api-design, calling-convention

I am trying to learn assembly, and I can get a few examples working, but this is mystifying.

How does the kernel know to grab what is in the `ecx` register as the pointer to user-space memory to display on `stdout`

```
mov edx,9       ;message length
mov ecx, name   ;message to write
mov ebx,1       ;file descriptor (stdout)
mov eax,4       ;system call number (sys_write)
int 0x80        ;call kernel
```

If edx is the universal data register, and eax is the universal input output, why would a kernel call be expecting data/output on the ecx register?

Comment: There's nothing "universal" about those designations.  They're just registers, places to store data.  How they are used is up to the software designer.  In this case, the people who wrote the kernel ABI decided that the system call's second argument should go in the ecx register, and the kernel code that implements the system call is written to get it from that register.

Comment: It's because the kernel looks in that register for that datum.  Linus could have also chosen to use a different register, but he didn't.

Answer (score 2):

The location of arguments is part of the ABI. Per https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/Interfacing_with_Linux#Making_a_syscall:

> Parameters are passed by setting the general purpose registers as following:
>
> ```
> Syscall # | Param 1 | Param 2 | Param 3 | Param 4 | Param 5 | Param 6
> eax       | ebx     | ecx     | edx     | esi     | edi     | ebp
>
> Return value
> eax
> ```

Answer (score 1):

> ... why would a kernal call be expecting data/output on the ecx register?

An interrupt is a special form of a sub-routine that works similar to a sub-routine you call using the `call` instruction.

When an interrupt is entered, the first thing which is done is to `push` all registers on the stack. This means that all registers will be stored in RAM memory (because the stack is RAM memory).

In Linux a function written in C programming language will be called from the assembler code.

In C programming language a `struct` can be used to access data stored in RAM if it is known how the data is stored. And because we know in which order we have written the `push` instructions in our assembler code, we can define a `struct` which can be used to access the data on the stack:

```
struct registers {
    unsigned long ebx;
    unsigned long ecx;
    unsigned long edx;
    ...
    unsigned long eax;
    unsigned long eip;
    ...
}
```

In the C-written function in the kernel we can now access this structure to read out the register values:

```
void systemCall_4(struct registers * regs)
{
    kernelFile * f;
    int (*pWrite)(kernelFile *,const void *,int);

    /* Get the file from the file handle */
    f = getFileFromHandle(regs->ebx);

    /* No such file */
    if(f == NULL)
    {
        regs->eax = ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE;
    }
    /* Call the device driver */
    else
    {
        pWrite = f->writeFunction;
        regs->eax = pWrite(f, (const void *)(regs->ecx), regs->edx);
    }
}
```

It was the decision of the kernel programmers to define that `ecx` points to the data and `edx` is the length.

In MS-DOS (for example) it is the other way round: `ecx` is the length and `edx` points to the data. So you see that the Linux developers also could have decided to do it differently.